# How to move child div to top if a change of text is detected

Tags: jquery, html

I have a parent div that houses 3 child divs. Is it possible to move a child div to the top if any change is detected within its text or link?

```
<div id="latest">
  <div class="post post-1"><a href="#">Post 1</a></div>
  <div class="post post-2"><a href="#">Post 2</a></div>
  <div class="post post-3"><a href="#">Post 3</a></div>
</div>
```

This is what I have so far, but no go:

```
$(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified", ".post a", function (){
  $(this).parent().prependTo(this);
});
```

Comment: how there will be change in the link??

Comment: @Ashishsah From .get().

Comment: Important note from MDN: **Be very careful** `with this event it is easy to cause an infinite loop if you decide to change the DOM inside the event handler.`

Comment: The problem is `parent()` is selecting from the `document` that has no parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can check mutation observers, if they will work for you. `DOMSubtreeModified` and other mutation events are [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events).

[MutationObserver WEB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

[DOM MutationObserver – reacting to DOM changes without killing browser performance](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/)

And inside the event found, you can clone your component and prepend it somewhere else on page.

```
$( "b" ).clone().prependTo( "p" )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code:

```
$(this).parent().prependTo(this);
```

It should be (with the less change possible):

```
$(this).parent().prependTo($(this).parent().parent());
```

because you want to prepend the .post to #latest, not its child (this).

[working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/amt8jkqw/3/)